# How to make a truly random playlist

Tags: data-synchronization, music.app, playlist

I have a playlist in Music.app that contains over a thousand songs.  My iPhone doesn't have enough storage to accept all of them without deleting apps.  So I created another playlist that says to take twelve hours worth at random.

Unfortunately, at every sync, it gets the **same** list of songs.  The only ways I can think of to get a different random sample is to delete and re-create the playlist, or to change random to something else and change it back.

**Is there some other simple trick to make it re-do the random sample at each sync?**

Comment: Ages ago when I still used iTunes/Apple Music, I used "recently played" as an extra filter to force iTunes to pick other tracks each time.

Comment: Well, there was no "recently played" in the list, but I put "last played not in the past ten days" and the first three didn't change.

Comment: It has been a while so my memory might be a bit hazy. But I remember it being a hazzle sometimes.